# Contractible Subspace and Homotopy Equivalence

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, homotopy-theory

It is known that if pair $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property and $A$ is contractible, then the quotient map $q:X\to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.

I am wondering what if the homotopy extension property is omitted. What would be a counterexample?  Namely, I am looking for a space $X$ and a contractible subspace $A$  such that the quotient map $q:X\to X/A$ is not a homotopy equivalence. I am thinking about the Hawaiian Earring but am not sure if it is a correct counterexample.

Comment: E.g. $X=S^1$, $A=S^1-pt$.